# Why is "t" sometimes pronounced like "d" in American English?

Tags: pronunciation, phonology, north-american-english, transatlantic-differences, flapping

Why, in American English, is the word *Italy* is pronounced /ˈɪdəli/ and not /ˈɪtəli/?
What is the rule that is followed in the pronunciation of *Italy* to make the letter t pronounced like a d? Why is the same rule not followed for *Italian*, which is pronounced /əˈtæljən/ or /ɪˈtæljən/?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**First two questions:** The pronunciation of some American English consonants can be quite different from British English, in particular for *R* and *T*. A *t* in the middle of a word can be pronunced as a soft *d* in American English (think of *bottle*, *cattle*, etc.). See [here](http://www.americanaccent.com/pronunciation.html), for example, for examples of this.

**Third question:** Why it does happen for *Italy* and not for *Italian* is clearly a matter of **stress**. If the stress is on the *t*, it usually keeps its pronunciation and is not changed into a soft *d*. Thus /ˈɪdəli/ but /əˈtæljən/. Another example is (taken from the *New Oxford American Dictionary*, in US English pronunciation): *tautology* (/tɔˈtɑlədʒi/) vs *tautological*
(/ˈˌtɔdlˈɑdʒəkəl/), which clearly demonstrate that.

Comment: It may be worth mentioning the glottal stop here which is characteristic of Northern English (my native tongue). The same rules apply as you outlined, but rather than the D sound there is, in fact, no sound!

Comment: @Dancrumb: Ah, but the glottal stop is just as much (or as little) a sound as any other occlusive consonant!

Comment: @Cerberus: I knew someone would pick me up on whether a glottal stop is a sound or not :o)

Comment: @Dancrumb: Hehe, yeah, that is the kind of place we have here!

Comment: The “soft” t sound of American English is usually described phonetically as a flap or tap and is represented in IPA with the “fishhook r” [ɾ] rather than [d].

Comment: @nohat: See, I said the US vs UK thing comes up all the time. ;-)

Comment: @Orbling this is a great answer that addresses the difference without being biased about it. All we need now is to rename the question to be less specific and we have a perfect question for our collection of British–American differences questions.

Comment: @nohat: Aye, good work.

Comment: @jwpat Not in the words quoted here, though: before a syllabic l or n, it is a true [d].

Comment: Erm, stress on a /t/ ?

Answer (score 9):

Not all Americans do, and not consistently.

Flap-t (/d/ instead of /t/) often happens between vowel sounds or after a vowel and before a liquid.

The t in "-teen" is always pronounced as t. As Henry mentions the reason is that flap rarely happens in stressed positions. As it doesn't happen in Italian.

[Here](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/blog.php?action=ViewBlogArticle&ba_id=74)'s good explanation of T pronounced D.

Comment: The flap rarely happens at start of a stressed syllable, as in *Italian*.  It is more common in an unstressed syllable, as in *Italy*.

Comment: Absolutely right.

Comment: Consonant softening (voiceless plosives becoming voiced, etc.) is normal in human language, although it is more likely (or, probably, simply faster to occur) between unstressed vowels. Writing -- artificially crystalising pronunciation -- is *not* the normal state of affairs. That's why *pasta e fagioli* comes out *pastafazool*, or *capicola* is pronounced something like *gabbagool*, in many Italian dialects. (And yes, I did understand that you meant it doesn't happen in the *word* Italian -- I'm just using Italian words to demonstrate that it isn't an English phenomenon.)

Comment: @Stan Rogers: Italian dialects are not dialects of [Italian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_language); they are completely different languages. To make an example, in some places of northern Italy they speak a dialect of the [Western Lombard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Lombard_dialects) or [Eastern Lombard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Lombard_language); in other places, they speak [Ladino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladino_language).

Comment: @kiamlaluno: The dialects I'm referring to are "merely" dialects of the standard Tuscan. If I had meant differently, I would have said so. (I am aware that Italy as a political entity is defined by geography rather than language.) Any natural "language" is just a collection of dialects (absent a controlling institution), and the phenomena that cause language to change from one to another is constantly at work in all of them.

Comment: @Stan Rogers _Capicola_ is not a word used in any dialect spoken in Italian, as far as I know; [Capicolla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capicola) is rather a word used in Canada.

Comment: (Also, dialects of standard Tuscan are dialects spoken in Tuscany. While Italian is based on Tuscan, it was influenced by other languages spoken in Italy.)

Answer (score 4):

There's no /d/.  It's /ɪtəli/ pronounced [ɪɾəli], with alveolar flap in the pronunciation corresponding to phonemic t.  It really is helpful, folks, to distinguish between phonemes and phones for a question like this.  If the schwa is lost in casual pronunciation, since you can't say a flap right next to an [l] (the tongue tip has to come back down for a flap), the flap becomes [d]: [ɪdli] (which does not happen in my pronunciation, but I've heard it).

Answer (score 1):

The determination of the sound is usually in rhythm. Different English dialects have different rhythms for words, which causes letters to get assimilated, softened, and dropped.

If you pronounce the t as t instead of d in a word like butter, the rhythm will be out of sync with American pronunciations. This is the same reason Brits often pronounce literally, litch-rally or lit-rally instead of lid-erally like Americans. They don't soften their t's and the rhythm of the e is faster in British English. As a result the t sound is either emphasized or assimilated into the ch sound.