# What's the correct pronunciation of "epitome": "Epi-tome" or "Epi-tuh-mi"?

Tags: pronunciation

A friend said that epitome is pronounced as `epi-tuh-mi` and not `epi-tome` (with the tome like home). 
Who is right? Also, is the pronunciation purely dependent on the region where you learnt English?

Comment: See the second answer in [What words are commonly mispronounced by literate people who read them before they heard them?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1431/what-words-are-commonly-mispronounced-by-literate-people-who-read-them-before-the/1685#1685) It actually comes up if you [search the site for "epitome"](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=epitome) (^_^)

Comment: Maybe something's wrong with the JavaScript support on my browser. The same thing was said about another question of mine. But, the truth is that the questions just don't turn up.

Comment: you might wish to post a bug report on the [meta site](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/), then.

Comment: @RegDwight, I shall

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Epitome* comes from Greek but it was introduced in English via the Medieval French *épitomé*.  It's now very rarely used in French, really found only in scholarly works.

Note the acute accent at the end.  This is why you pronounce it with an 'i'. 
For instance: Beauté => Beauty.

Comment: So, I was wrong. :'(

Comment: Of course, French has that accent **because** it was highly stressed in Greek: ἐπιτομή. It's the long eta "ē" *and* the syllable taking the stress for the whole word.

Answer (score 3):

As reported by the NOAD and the OED, *Epitome* is pronounced /əˈpɪdəmi/ in American English and /ɪˈpɪtəmi/ (or /ɛˈpɪtəmi/) in British English.

Comment: Both the American Heritage and Merriam-Webster dictionaries say that it's pronounced /ɪˈpɪtəmi/ in American English as well. Of course, it's difficult to tell /ə/ from /ɪ/ in an unstressed syllable.

Comment: @Peter Shor Usually, in American English a non accented _t_ that is not at the beginning (nor at the end) of a word is pronounced /d/, as in _Italy_; _Ito, Prince Hirobumi_; _cartage_; _Carter, Angela_; _aorta_; etc.

Comment: @kiamlaluna: But if this is a feature of your accent (definitely *not* universal in American English), you distinguish between a "t" and the "d" by the length of the preceding vowel, so catty and caddy are still pronounced differently, even if the "t" and "d" are pronounced the same. With due respects to the NOAD, I think prescribing the /d/ in pronunciation guides is just likely to confuse everybody.

Comment: @Peter Shor No, it is not a feature of my accent. The NOAD is not the only American dictionary that reports that pronunciation of _Italy_. See also [Why is "t" sometimes pronounced like "d" in American English?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13980/why-is-t-sometimes-pronounced-like-d-in-american-english). As for the pronunciation of _catty_ and _caddy_, the NOAD reports that both the words are pronounced /ˈkædi/.

Comment: @Peter Shor To notice that one of the answers of that question contains a link to a Merriam-Webster's post: [Do Americans pronounce T like D?](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/blog.php?action=ViewBlogArticle&ba_id=74)

Comment: @kiamlaluna: I believe the NOAD is wrong; they're pronounced differently. See the [vowel length](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vowel_length#Allophonic_vowel_length) wikipedia page. Catty is pronounced /ˈkædi/ while caddy is pronounced[ˈkæˑdi]. What happened phonetically is presumably that once the length of the vowel became a distinguishing mark between voiced and unvoiced consonants, Americans became lazy about distinguishing their t's from d's in certain situations.

Comment: @kiamlaluna: thanks for the links. So, to summarize, Americans do distinguish between the phonemes /t/ and /d/ at the beginning of unstressed syllables, but many do this just by lengthening the previous syllable. Most of them probably don't even realize they're pronouncing the "t" and "d" the same in *catty* and *caddy.* This does mean the phonemes "t" and "d" merge between two unstressed syllables, so the last two syllables of *quantity* and *chickadee* would be pronounced identically. Brits then hear Americans as pronouncing "t"s and "d"s identically.

Comment: @Peter Shor It's _kiamlaluno_, not _kiamlaluna_. The _American Accent Training_ (ISBN 0-7641-1429-8), which is edited and published in the United States of America, reports that the pronunciation of _Italy_ is (they don't use the IPA) _id'ly_, and the pronunciation of "Betty bought a bit of better butter" is "Beddy bä də bihda bedder budder." I am not talking of the difference between _t_ and _d_, which is well clear to any American, but how the _t_ is pronounced in American English.

Comment: @kiamlaluno even the website that you linked from www.learnersdictionary.com says "t" is not pronounced "d", but it's a different sound, a "flap/tap".

Comment: If anybody's still reading this, I just realized why Americans use a /dʒ/ in the pronunication of *congratulations*. It was probably originally pronunced /kənˌgrætjuˈleɪʃənz/, much closer to the British pronunciation. I suspect that first, the /t/ turned into a /d/, and then the /dj/ turned into a /dʒ/, giving /kənˌgrædʒuˈleɪʃənz/. (Merriam-Webster says both /tʃ/ and /dʒ/ are valid pronunciations, but does not mention /tj/; I use /dʒ/.)

Comment: The NOAD reports /kənɡrætʃəˈleɪʃən/ as pronunciation of _congratulation_.