# How exactly to pronounce 'alphabetical' and 'pharmaceutical' in American English

Tags: pronunciation, american-english

How does one pronounce 'alphabetical' and 'pharmaceutical' in American English?

Is it  **phar•ma•ceu•di•cal** or **phar•ma•ceu•i•cal**? And is it **al•pha•bet•di•cal** or **al•pha•bet•i•cal**?

Do you pronounce 'ti' as 'di' or do you pronounce just the 'i' with the 't' silent?

Comment: I would pronounce the 't' as'ti' but I'm British

Comment: Related question: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13980/why-is-t-sometimes-pronounced-like-d-in-american-english

Comment: Why was this closed as general reference? Intermedial 't's are usually not described in references as a dental flap for AmE in dictionaries, online or otherwise. Of course it should be closed as 'exact duplicate' from @BoofusMcGoofus 's comment.

Answer (score 4):

A *t* in the middle of a word is often pronounced as a soft *d* in American English.  (I think the sound is technically known as a *flap* or *tap*.)  In both of the words you've asked about, most Americans are likely to make a sound closer to a *d* than a *t*.

[This page](http://www.antimoon.com/how/flap-t.htm) has some sound files with flapped and un-flapped t's, if you'd like an example of what that sounds like.

Answer (score 1):

These words are **not** pronounced with *d* in American. They are pronounced with an [alveolar flap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alveolar_flap). In general American, this consonant replaces both *t* and *d* when they lie between two vowels, the first of which is stressed, and it sounds very much like a *d* to British ears.

If you pronounce these words with a regular t, Americans will understand you perfectly, although it will contribute to an impression of a foreign accent (my guess is that it would sound like a very slight Spanish accent if you pronounce everything but these *t*'s and *d*'s the way Americans do). If you pronounce these words with a regular *d,* I believe Americans would be more likely to misunderstand you, although I don't know whether anybody has studied it.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, mgb is correct, 't' is pronounced 'ti'
Pharmaceutical is pronounced phar·ma·ceu·ti·cal.
Alphabetical is pronounced al·pha·bet·i·cal.

Comment: Is your answer about British English? The OP is asking about AmE.

Comment: No, American english. I am an American.